# What does the keyword `var` do in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I see it in some contract examples, but it doesn't look like it has the exact same purpose as [regular JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Can it be used to initialize variables in a specific scope without declaring a type?

Comment: Where did you see that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[From the docs:](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#type-deduction)

> #### Type Deduction
>
> For convenience, it is not always necessary to explicitly specify the type of a variable, the compiler automatically infers it from the type of the first expression that is assigned to the variable:

```
uint24 x = 0x123;
var y = x;
```

Here, the type of `y` will be `uint24`. Using `var` is not possible for function parameters or return parameters.

This is also a *must* for **[Destructuring Assignments](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#destructuring-assignments-and-returning-multiple-values)**

```
function f() public pure returns (uint, bool, uint) {
        return (7, true, 2);
}
var (x,y,z) = f(); //Multi-Return from Fx

(x,y) = (y,x) //Swap Values
```

Comment: The `var` keyword is being deprecated in 0.4.20, see [https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.20](release notes).

Comment: @Jaryl, that link is broken

Comment: Oops, the correct link is here https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.20